# Pop!_OS after install missing windows 10 efi file `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft`

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-loader

After install Pop!_OS, I can't boot to windows 10, the `efibootmgr -v` output is

```
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0006,9999,0000,0001
Boot0000  ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ab8f019d-3b03-42b0-b780-36e72172e012,0x800,0x3c800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ab8f019d-3b03-42b0-b780-36e72172e012,0x800,0x3c800)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...h................
Boot0005* Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS HD(1,GPT,8aef89ff-532e-40c6-b8c7-9820bd395c44,0x800,0xf9fff)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot0006* Solid State Disk  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-25-38-56-91-50-BE-B1)/HD(1,GPT,8aef89ff-532e-40c6-b8c7-9820bd395c44,0x800,0xf9fff)..BO
Boot9999* USB Drive (UEFI)  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(16,0)..BO
```

and `sudo ls -alh /boot/efi/EFI` is

```
drwx------ 6 root root 4.0K 6月  26 04:42 .
drwx------ 5 root root 4.0K 1月   1  1970 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K 6月  26 02:17 BOOT
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K 6月  26 02:17 Linux
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K 6月  26 02:17 Pop_OS-95cc6f8e-6c19-4fa1-ad32-6ee13ef0e786
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K 6月  26 02:17 systemd
```

the `Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` does not exists, how can I fix this? Thank you! I have try copy windows `C:\windows\Boot\EFI\bootmgfw.efi` to linux `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, but still can't boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no sub-directory `ubuntu` at `/boot/efi/EFI` either, so unfortunately it looks like you may have overwritten the whole disk when installing Pop!_OS. Or at the very least, you have accidentally formatted the EFI System Partition, causing the bootloaders of any other OS you had installed to be lost.

The Windows bootloader needs many files: one of them is `BCD` which is tailored for your system, so it cannot be copied but needs to be regenerated for your system specifically.

If the system partition of Windows is still present on the disk, the easiest way to restore the Windows bootloader would be to boot from a Windows installation media, select "Repair your computer", "Troubleshoot" then "Automatic Repair". [Here is a description with pictures.](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/fix-uefi-boot-in-windows-10-8-7.html#1)

After that, you might find that Windows has made itself the default boot option, but that should be fixable by going to the BIOS settings and adjusting the boot order to make "Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS" the first one again.

If you also have Ubuntu installed, you might want to re-install its GRUB too: although Pop!_OS's GRUB might be auto-detecting Ubuntu and offering it as an option in its GRUB boot menu, Ubuntu will be dependent on Pop!_OS's bootloader until you reinstall it. So if you remove Pop!_OS in the future, you will have no way to get into Ubuntu unless you had fixed this first.

You also might have some minor problems installing kernel and/or GRUB updates to Ubuntu, as the update package may attempt to update GRUB configuration and find it no longer in the expected location.

Comment: Thank you, I format the efi partition before install, I now use the PE system and bdcboot command to re-establish the windows efi